# Dictionary creator (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, dictionary

Rather than typing manually all the monsters I want to use in my text game, I want to build a program to automatically add to the dictionary via IDLE.  My question is how to collect and save the new monsters I add in IDLE.  Is there a way to make a program that would write the information into a notepad? I looked for similiar answers and didn't see anything.  But I don't necessarily know the right terminology.  Thanks!

```
"""
Dictionary of indexed "monsters" for text game
"""
### Premade dictionary
mondic =  {1:'dragon',
           2:'angry gnome vigilante',
           3:'Donald Trump',
           4:'lambhorn rider',
           5:'bone cancer'}
print(mondic)
check = 'yes'
x = 5
### Create new monsters
while check == 'yes':
    print('Do you want to create a monster?')
    check = str(input('yes/no '))
    if check == 'no':
        break
    new_monster = str(input('New monster name: '))
    x += 1
    mondic[new_monster] = x
print(mondic)
```

Comment: Write into a notepad? You mean like a text file that you open in notepad? If so, sure. It's just writing to a file.

Comment: Consider the `pickle` or `json` modules?

Comment: You seem to have `mondic[new_monster] = x` where you meant `mondic[x] = new_monster`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I will look into those modules, I just started python so I am not too familiar with them

Comment: @DanD.I want the key to just be a unique number that is automatically generated, that way I can store any information about the monsters as a list

Comment: You can use a file (see answer below by Jacob H), or you can use any modules in "Data persistence" (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html): `pickle` was mentioned above, you can also use `dbm` or `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use a dictionary for this. Because you are just storing the names at indices, a list is much better suited for this problem. You will want code like this:

```
monlist = ['dragon', 'angry gnome vigilante', 'Donald Trump', 'lambhorn rider', 'bone cancer']
while check == 'y':
    check = input('Do you want to create a monster? (y/n): ')
    if check == 'n':
        break
    new_monster = input('New monster name: ')
    monlist.append(new_monster)
```

Then to write these to a file:

```
fv = open("filename.txt", 'w') # 'w' for write
for monster in monlist:
    print(monster, file=fv)
fv.close() # close the file
```

And to read:

```
monlist = []
open("filename.txt", 'w')
for line in fv:
    monlist.append(line)
fv.close()
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for more information. Keep in mind that there are other ways to read and write data, and as you get further into your project you may discover that you need to write your own classes or actually use a dictionary. Then you may need to serialize data, use json encoding, or find some other way to save/read data. Good luck!

Comment: And note: Should you want a numeric "key", the index in the `list` serves as a key; using the `enumerate` function when iterating would get you the index, value pairs for free.